# Spring AOP declaractive transaction manager

Tags: spring, transactions, aop, jta

In the Spring declarative transaction manager:
My configuration tx:method:

```
<tx:method name="handle*" propagation="REQUIRED" no-rollback-for="java.lang.RuntimeException" rollback-for="java.lang.Exception" read-only="false"/>
```

Spring
rollback-for documentation is : The Exception(s) that will trigger rollback; comma-delimited. For example, 'com.foo.MyBusinessException,ServletException'

no-rollback-for documentation is: The Exception(s) that will *not* trigger rollback; comma-delimited. For example, 'com.foo.MyBusinessException,ServletException'

I want the transaction manager rollback when catch the java.lang.Exception but the java.lang.RuntimeException will result commit.

Is this configuration work for my request? 
what relationship about ： no-rollback-for and rollback-for in tx:method of tx:advice?

Comment: I have answerd your question, but is that realy what you want to do: commit for an not expected (Runtime) exception and rollback when an declared exception in thrown?

Answer (score 0):

In short

It does what you want.

---

The most specific (no)-rollback-for rule that match the concreate throwing exception is winning.

This mean if you have an exception hierarchy and the rollback rules

- A (extends Exception)  <-- rollback
- B extends A
- C extends B            <-- no rollback
- D extends C
- E extends D            <-- rollback
- F extends E

Then an thrown exception of class A, B, E and F will rollback, but C and D will not.

(It is implemented in `RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.rollBackOn(Throwable ex)`)

Comment: I read the     RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.rollBackOn(Throwable ex)) `code`if (winner == null) {
   logger.trace("No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules");
   return super.rollbackOn(ex);
  }
   
  return !(winner instanceof NoRollbackRuleAttribute);

Comment: Example: if my program throw NullPointerException, the rollback-rule handle this exception, and the NullPointerException is instanceof RuntimeException, so it will return false, and the transactionManager will commit it.

Comment: if the program throw some kinds of non-RuntimeException.the transactionManager will rollback it.

Comment: Yes, I have test it with few cases.`1.I throw java.lang.RuntimeException --->the result is:transactionManager commit the transaction; `    `2.I throw java.lang.Exception---> the result is:transactionManager rollback the transaction.`

Comment: @niken: And? - that is what you want: "I want the transaction manager rollback when catch the java.lang.Exception but the java.lang.RuntimeException will result commit." -- so what is the problem?

Comment: yes.The problem is:I am not sure what the relationship between no-rollback-for and rollback-for.What I am worry about is: the program throw java.lang.RuntimeException, I want the program to commit; I just make sure it is true.

Comment: That is what I have writen: the more specific configuration in the one that is taken in accout!